# How to programmatically instantiate a Toolbar in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I've looked all over the Internet but for some reason couldn't find anyone mention how can we instantiate a toolbar 100% programmatically.

Most of them talk about using the XML. I already know how to do that. But I want to know how to use only code to instantiate it.

I tried doing something like:

```
Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar(this);
toolbar.setTitle("This is a title");
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

but it doesn't seem to show up. This is strange that I can't find a single article discussing this online. Maybe it's not possible? Would appreciate guidance.

Comment: @Enzokie Sorry, that was a mistake. I actually have `this` as context, and it doesn't work. Am I missing something else?

Comment: You need to attach it inside in a layout programatically inorder to appear.

Comment: This will help you https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Toolbar` Programatically this way

```
Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar(this);
Toolbar.LayoutParams toolBarParams = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(
                Toolbar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                R.attr.actionBarSize
        );
toolbar.setLayoutParams(toolBarParams);
```

and then attach to your layout.

Comment: @Vlad gald to know that.